# (#2635) You are calling a deprecated version of the Ads API. Please update to the latest version: v5.0 error showed up, even updated gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, sdk

I have updated facebook-ruby-business-SDK to 5.0 Also in my FB app setting, set the API version 5.0. However, Making calls through SDK is giving a deprecated error. [image: app setting.]

Please note, graph API with 5.0 is working.

Comment: What API call are you doing when you get the error?

Comment: With multiple endpoint like to upload images, creating ads. In short, when I use the ad account SDK, it gives errors.